# WMI remote connect in c# uses wrong username

Tags: c#, wmi, remote-server, access-denied

I'm trying to create program in C#, that will retrieve some data from local or remote server. Local part is working great, remote connection does not at all. I'm getting access denied.

Here is the code

```
public void ConnectToWmi()
{
  var options = new ConnectionOptions();
  options.Username = "admin";
  options.Password = "admin";
  options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
  options.EnablePrivileges = true;

  var scope = new ManagementScope("\\SERVER_NAME\root\cimv2",options);
  scope.Connect();          
}
```

I have verified using wbemtest.exe, that connection acctually works.
When I examinated both connections using Wireshark I noticed strange thing - wbemtest is sending correct username "admin" but my program is sending username of current user logged on computer.

So i experimented a little and created administrator account with credentials **username** "admin" **password** "admin" on computer that I'm running my program on. And it works!

So in short: Why is my C# program using credentials of currently logged in user instead of credentials that I supplied to it in the code?

**more info**

- server is running as virtual machine in Hyper V on my notebook
- client OS is win 8.1, server is win 7
- connection between client and server works and all firewalls are disabled